# What Should Be In My Return?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python to parse an XML response from a SOAP web-service. The `Customer` returns about 40 values as you can see below. I would like to know if there is a way to make it so I only have to type one thing into my `return` statement and get all of the values returned? I tried to use `for customer in doc.findall('.//Customer').itervalues()` and that did not work as I believe that call is for dictionaries. Same results and reasoning behind `.iteritems`.

```
 doc = ET.fromstring(response_xml)
for customer in doc.findall('.//Customer'):
    customer_number = customer.findtext('CustomerNumber')
    customer_first_name = customer.findtext('FirstName')
    customer_last_name = customer.findtext('LastName')
    customer_middle_name = customer.findtext('MiddleName')
    customer_salutation = customer.findtext('Salutation')
    customer_gender = customer.findtext('Gender')
    customer_language = customer.findtext('Language')
    customer_address1 = customer.findtext('Address1')
    customer_address2 = customer.findtext('Address2')
    customer_address3 = customer.findtext('Address3')
    customer_city = customer.findtext('City')
    customer_county = customer.findtext('County')
    customer_state_code = customer.findtext('StateCode')
    customer_zip_code = customer.findtext('ZipCode')
    customer_phone_number = customer.findtext('PhoneNumber')
    customer_business_phone = customer.findtext('BusinessPhone')
    customer_business_ext = customer.findtext('BusinessExt')
    customer_fax_number = customer.findtext('FaxNumber')
    customer_birth_date = customer.findtext('BirthDate')
    customer_drivers_license = customer.findtext('DriversLicense')
    customer_contact = customer.findtext('Contact')
    customer_preferred_contact = customer.findtext('PreferredContact')
    customer_mail_code = customer.findtext('MailCode')
    customer_tax_exempt_Number = customer.findtext('TaxExmptNumber')
    customer_assigned_salesperson = customer.findtext('AssignedSalesperson')
    customer_type = customer.findtext('CustomerType')
    customer_preferred_phone = customer.findtext('PreferredPhone')
    customer_cell_phone = customer.findtext('CellPhone')
    customer_page_phone = customer.findtext('PagePhone')
    customer_other_phone = customer.findtext('OtherPhone')
    customer_other_phone_desc = customer.findtext('OtherPhoneDesc')
    customer_email1 = customer.findtext('Email1')
    customer_email2 = customer.findtext('Email2')
    customer_optional_field = customer.findtext('OptionalField')
    customer_allow_contact_postal = customer.findtext('AllowContactByPostal')
    customer_allow_contact_phone = customer.findtext('AllowContactByPhone')
    customer_allow_contact_email = customer.findtext('AllowContactByEmail')
    customer_business_phone_ext = customer.findtext('BusinessPhoneExtension')
    customer_internatinol_bus_phone = customer.findtext('InternationalBusinessPhone')
    customer_international_cell = customer.findtext('InternationalCellPhone')
    customer_external_x_reference_key = customer.findtext('ExternalCrossReferenceKey')
    customer_international_fax = customer.findtext('InternationalFaxNumber')
    customer_international_other_phone = customer.findtext('InternationalOtherPhone')
    customer_international_home_phone = customer.findtext('InternationalHomePhone')
    customer_preferred_name = customer.findtext('CustomerPreferredName')
    customer_international_pager = customer.findtext('InternationalPagerPhone')
    customer_preferred_lang = customer.findtext('PreferredLanguage')
    customer_last_change_date = customer.findtext('LastChangeDate')
    customer_vehicles = customer.findtext('Vehicles')
    customer_ccid = customer.findtext('CCID')
    customer_cccd = customer.findtext('CCCD')


webservice.close()
return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write that as a generator function yielding dicts where the key matches the `findtext` argument, e.g.:

```
fields = ['CustomerNumber', 'FirstName', 'LastName',
          # ...
         ]
for customer in doc.findall('.//Customer'):
    yield dict((f, customer.findtext(f)) for f in fields)
```

Comment: Apparently I cannot do this solution in 2.7 :(

Comment: `Python versions < 3.3 do not allow 'return' with arguments inside a generator`

Comment: Once I figured out what I was doing, this worked beautifully. Thank you for a very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You either want to return a `list` of `dict`s:

```
customers = []
for customer in doc.findall('.//Customer'):
    customer_dict = {}
    customer_dict['number']     = customer.findtext('CustomerNumber')
    customer_dict['first_name'] = customer.findtext('FirstName')
    customer_dict['last_name']  = customer.findtext('LastName')
    # ad nauseum
    customers.append(customer_dict)

webservice.close()
return customers
```

Or you make a `Customer` class that handles this, and you return a `list` of customer instances.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
doc = ET.fromstring(response_xml)
customers = {}
cust_dict = {}
for customer in doc.findall('.//Customer'):
    cust_dict['customer_number'] = customer.findtext('CustomerNumber')
    cust_dict['customer_first_name'] = customer.findtext('FirstName')
    cust_dict['customer_last_name'] = customer.findtext('LastName')
    snip snip...
    customers[customer_number] = cust_dict  # or whatever property you want to use to identify each customer, I'm assuming customer_number is some sort of id number        

webservice.close()
return  customers
```

That is if you don't have a class you can use to create a `Customer` object.